# How to use inspect to get the caller's info from callee in Python?

Tags: python, inspect

I need to get the caller info (what file/what line) from the callee. I learned that I can use the inspect module for that purpose, but not exactly how.

How do you get that info with inspection? Or is there any other way to get the info?

```
import inspect

print __file__
c=inspect.currentframe()
print c.f_lineno

def hello():
    print inspect.stack
    ?? what file called me in what line?

hello()
```

Answer (score 130, accepted):

The caller's frame is one frame higher than the current frame. You can use [`inspect.currentframe().f_back`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#types-and-members) to find the caller's frame.
Then use [inspect.getframeinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getframeinfo) to get the caller's filename and line number.

```py
import inspect


def hello():
    previous_frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back

    (
        filename,
        line_number,
        function_name,
        lines,
        index,
    ) = inspect.getframeinfo(previous_frame)

    return (filename, line_number, function_name, lines, index)


print(hello())

# ('/home/unutbu/pybin/test.py', 10, '<module>', ['hello()\n'], 0)
```

Comment: @prosseek: To get the caller's caller, just change the index `[1]` to `[2]`. (`inspect.getouterframes` returns a list of frames...). Python is beautifully organized.

Comment: You can also use inspect.currentframe().f_back.

Comment: This doesn't seem to provide a way to get the full path of the filename.

Comment: @JasonS: "the filename in the stack frame is [relative to the start up directory](https://doughellmann.com/blog/2012/04/30/determining-the-name-of-a-process-from-python/) of the application".

Comment: @unutbu: you somehow read my mind; this is in sphinx and it changed the current directory so i need the startup directory via sys.path[0].

Comment: This code sample works but performs pretty poorly. If you're only interested in a single frame and not the whole stack trace, you can get the previous frame and inspect it for the frame info:            

```filename, line_number, clsname, lines, index = inspect.getframeinfo(sys._getframe(1))```

Comment: @Mouscellaneous that is a huge savings, brings my time from ~30 ms to ~4 ms per call. One nice feature also is I can do this: `calling_function = inspect.getframeinfo(sys._getframe(1))[2]` so I don't have to waste memory with all those other variables that I don't care about. I just pull the calling function name

Comment: @Mouscellaneous: Thanks for the improvement!

Comment: The years roll past, yet this answer os still amazingly useful.

Answer (score 54):

I would suggest to use `inspect.stack` instead:

```
import inspect

def hello():
    frame,filename,line_number,function_name,lines,index = inspect.stack()[1]
    print(frame,filename,line_number,function_name,lines,index)
hello()
```

Comment: How is it better than using `getouterframes` as suggested by @unutbu?

Comment: It is more compact and better reflects the intent.

Comment: Note that `getouterframes(currentframe())` and `stack()` are equivalent under the hood https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/inspect.py#L1442

Comment: Another reason using stack() is nice is that it shows how to easily get other frames.  If, for example. your hello() function is called by another function first, you can update it to go two levels back.

Comment: I have profiled my code and it turned out that `stack()` is much slower that `sys._getframe(1).f_lineno`. In 1e6 calls it add 10 mins in my Linux environment.

Answer (score 2):

I published a wrapper for inspect with simple stackframe addressing covering the stack frame by a single parameter `spos`:

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysourceinfo/
- https://pythonhosted.org/pysourceinfo/

E.g. `pysourceinfo.PySourceInfo.getCallerLinenumber(spos=1)`

where `spos=0` is the lib-function, `spos=1` is the caller, `spos=2` the caller-of-the-caller, etc.

Answer (score -9):

If the caller is the main file, simply use sys.argv[0]