# Explain the concept of a stack frame in a nutshell

Tags: callstack

It seems that I get the idea of *call stack* in programming language design. But I cannot find (probably, I just don't search hard enough) any decent explanation of what *stack frame* is.

So I would like to ask someone to explain it to me in a few words.

Answer (score 262, accepted):

A stack frame is a frame of data that gets pushed onto the stack. In the case of a call stack, a stack frame would represent a function call and its argument data.

If I remember correctly, the function return address is pushed onto the stack first, then the arguments and space for local variables. Together, they make the "frame," although this is likely architecture-dependent. The processor knows how many bytes are in each frame and moves the stack pointer accordingly as frames are pushed and popped off the stack.

#### EDIT:

There is a big difference between higher-level call stacks and the processor's call stack.

When we talk about a processor's call stack, we are talking about working with addresses and values at the *byte/word level* in assembly or machine code. There are "call stacks" when talking about higher-level languages, but they are a debugging/runtime tool managed by the runtime environment so that you can log what went wrong with your program (at a high level). At this level, things like line numbers and method and class names are often known. By the time the processor gets the code, it has absolutely no concept of these things.

Comment: "The processor knows how many bytes are in each frame and moves the stack pointer accordingly as frames are pushed and popped off the stack." - I doubt the processor knows anything about stack, because WE manipulate it via subbing (allocation), pushing and popping. And so here are calling conventions which explain how we should use the stack.

Comment: Processor has stack-frame pointers, registers  that contain the address of the function’s frame.

Answer (score 149):

If you understand stack very well then you will understand how memory works in program and if you understand how memory works in program you will understand how function store in program and if you understand how function store in program you will understand how recursive function works and if you understand how recursive function works you will understand how compiler works and if you understand how compiler works your mind will works as compiler and you will debug any program very easily

Let me explain how stack works:

First you have to know how functions are represented in stack :

Heap stores dynamically allocated values.
Stack stores automatic allocation and deletion values.

[image]

Let's understand with example :

```
def hello(x):
    if x==1:
        return "op"
    else:
        u=1
        e=12
        s=hello(x-1)
        e+=1
        print(s)
        print(x)
        u+=1
    return e

hello(4)
```

Now understand parts of this program :

[image]

Now let's see what is stack and what are stack parts:

[image]

> Allocation of the stack :

Remember one thing: if any function's return condition gets satisfied, no matter it has loaded the local variables or not, it will immediately return from stack with it's stack frame. It means that whenever any recursive function get base condition satisfied and we put a return after base condition, the base condition will not wait to load local variables which are located in the “else” part of program. It will immediately return the current frame from the stack following which the next frame is now in the activation record.

See this in practice:

[image]

> Deallocation of the block:

So now whenever a function encounters return statement, it delete the current frame from the stack.

While returning from the stack, values will returned in reverse of the original order in which they were allocated in stack.

[image]

Comment: the stack grows downward and the heap grows upward, you have them reversed in your diagram. [CORRECT DIAGRAM HERE](http://www.andrew.cmu.edu/course/15-440-s12/applications/ln/proccontext.jpg)

Comment: @Rafael sorry for confusion , I was  talking about Direction of growth i was not talking about direction of stack growth. There are difference between direction of growth and direction of stack growth . See Here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677415/does-stack-grow-upward-or-downward

Comment: Rafael is right. Also the first picture is wrong. Replace it with something else  (search google pictures for "heap stack").

Comment: So if I understand correctly, in your third diagram, there are 3 stack frames because `hello()` has recursively called `hello()` which has then (again) recursively called `hello()`, and the global frame is original function which called the first `hello()`?

Comment: Where do the links lead us?? As a  serious concern of security these links should be removed as soon as possible.

Answer (score 68):

A quick wrap up. Maybe someone has a better explanation.

A call stack is composed of 1 or many several stack frames. Each stack frame corresponds to a call to a *function* or *procedure* which has **not** yet terminated with a return.

To use a stack frame, a thread keeps two pointers, one is called the *Stack Pointer* (**SP**), and the other is called the *Frame Pointer* (**FP**). **SP** always **points** *to the "top" of the* **stack**, and **FP** always **points** *to the "top" of the* **frame**. Additionally, the thread also maintains a *program counter* (**PC**) which points to the next instruction to be executed.

The following are stored on the stack:

- local variables and temporaries;
- actual parameters of the current instruction (procedure, function,
  etc.).

There are different calling conventions regarding the cleaning of the stack.

Comment: Don't forget that the subroutine's return address goes on the stack.

Comment: Frame Pointer is also Base Pointer in x86 terms

Comment: I would like to stress that a frame pointer points to the beginning of the stack frame for the currently active procedure incarnation.

Answer (score 20):

"A call stack is composed of stack frames..." — [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack#Structure)

A stack frame is a thing that you put on the stack. They are data structures that contain information about subroutines to call.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea how I missed this on wiki. Thanks. Do I understand correctly, that in dynamic languages the size of the frame is not a constant value since the locals of the function are not exactly known?

Comment: The size and nature of a frame is heavily dependent on the machine's architecture. In fact, the very paradigm of a call stack is architecture-specific. As far as I know it's always variable because different function calls will have different amounts of argument data.

Comment: Note that the size of the stack frame *must* be known by the processor when it's being manipulated. When this is happening, the size of the data is already determined. Dynamic languages are compiled to machine code just like static languages, but are often done just-in-time so that the compiler can maintain the dynamism and  the processor can work with "known" frame sizes. Don't confuse higher-level languages with machine code/assembly, which is where this stuff is actually happening.

Comment: Well, but dynamic languages also have their call stacks, don't they? I mean, if, say, Python wants to execute some procedure, the data about this procedure is stored inside of some Python interpreter's structure, am I correct? So I mean that call stack is present not only at a low level.

Comment: After reading a bit of that wikipedia article, I stand corrected (a bit). The size of the stack frame can remain unknown at *compile time*. But by the time the processor is working with stack + frame pointers, it has to know what the sizes are. The size can be variable but the processor knows the size, is what I was trying to say.

Comment: Also, stacks can be present at a higher level, but it would be sort of a "virtual stack." The processor has its own call stack. So again, don't confuse the two.

Comment: It occurs to me that you are probably confusing the two =). When you're programming at a higher level, often you catch an exception and then "print the call stack." This is a very different thing than printing the processor's call stack (which you can do, for example, in Visual Studio, but it will show you assembly code). Runtime environments keep a stack of function calls, so that you can keep track as a programmer of what your program is doing. But the answers you're getting here are about the low-level processor call stack.

Comment: Thanks, but I was particularly interested about the second one. Maybe I really was confusing the two, but from my point they are quite similar and serve for similar purposes. Anyway, thank you very much!

Comment: I haven't personally seen "stack frames" at the high-level, but it looks like Python has the concept. Here's a question that talks about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711184/how-to-use-inspect-to-get-the-callers-info-from-callee It sounds like your question was Python-specific and you didn't realize it =P

Comment: Yeap, this is quite possible. Not realizing what the stack frame is, I could not possibly realize that it has to do with Python only :)

Answer (score 7):

Programmers may have questions about stack frames not in a broad term (that it is a singe entity in the stack that serves just one function call and keeps return address, arguments and local variables) but in a narrow sense – when the term `stack frames` is mentioned in context of compiler options.

Whether the author of the question has meant it or not, but the concept of a stack frame from the aspect of compiler options is a very important issue, not covered by the other replies here.

For example, Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 C/C++ compiler has the following option related to `stack frames`:

- /Oy  (Frame-Pointer Omission)

GCC have the following:

- -fomit-frame-pointer (Don't keep the frame pointer in a register for functions that don't need one. This avoids the instructions to save, set up and restore frame pointers; it also makes an extra register available in many functions)

Intel C++ Compiler have the following:

- -fomit-frame-pointer (Determines whether EBP is used as a general-purpose register in optimizations)

which has the following alias:

- /Oy

Delphi has the following command-line option:

- -$W+  (Generate Stack Frames)

In that specific sense, from the compiler’s perspective, a stack frame is just the *entry and exit code for the routine*, that pushes an anchor to the stack – that can also be used for debugging and for exception handling. Debugging tools may scan the stack data and use these anchors for backtracing, while locating `call sites` in the stack, i.e. to display names of the functions in the order they have been called hierarchically. For Intel architecture, it is `push ebp; mov ebp, esp` or `enter` for entry and `mov esp, ebp; pop ebp` or `leave` for exit.

That’s why it is very important to understand for a programmer what a stack frame is in when it comes to compiler options – because the compiler can control whether to generate this code or not.

In some cases, the stack frame (entry and exit code for the routine) can be omitted by the compiler, and the variables will directly be accessed via the stack pointer (SP/ESP/RSP) rather than the convenient base pointer (BP/ESP/RSP).
Conditions for omission of the stack frame, for example:

- the function is a leaf function (i.e. an end-entity that doesn’t call other functions);
- there are no try/finally or try/except or similar constructs, i.e. no exceptions are used;
- no routines are called with outgoing parameters on the stack;
- the function has no parameters;
- the function has no inline assembly code;
- etc...

Omitting stack frames (entry and exit code for the routine) can make code smaller and faster, but it may also negatively affect the debuggers’ ability to backtrace the data in the stack and to display it to the programmer. These are the compiler options that determine under which conditions a function should have the entry and exit code, for example: (a) always, (b) never, (c) when needed (specifying the conditions).

Answer (score -1):

Stack frame is the packed information related to a function call. This information generally includes arguments passed to th function, local variables and where to return upon terminating. Activation record is another name for a stack frame. The layout of the stack frame is determined in the ABI by the manufacturer and every compiler supporting the ISA must conform to this standard, however layout scheme can be compiler dependent. Generally stack frame size is not limited but there is a concept called "red/protected zone" to allow system calls...etc to execute without interfering with a stack frame.

There is always a SP but on some ABIs (ARM's and PowerPC's for example) FP is optional. Arguments that needed to be placed onto the stack can be offsetted using the SP only. Whether a stack frame is generated for a function call or not depends on the type and number of arguments, local variables and how local variables are accessed generally. On most ISAs, first, registers are used and if there are more arguments than registers dedicated to pass arguments these are placed onto the stack (For example x86 ABI has 6 registers to pass integer arguments). Hence, sometimes, some functions do not need a stack frame to be placed on the stack, just the return address is pushed onto the stack.