# angular1 - angular.js:11655 RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive that has a controller with a $http call to an endpoint. I'd like to take the results of that server call and then display them in my template. If I have a single value inside my template, and then set it explicitly, it all works fine. If I try to bind the template to the server call then I get the error mentioned above. Do I need to use the $compile service for this to work?

thanks in advance

**Final result with compilation**

```
function mydirective(myservice,$compile) {

    return {
        restrict: 'ACE',
        scope: {
            url: '=',
            title: '=',
        },

        controllerAs: 'ctrl',
        bindToController: true,
        controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
            myservice.init('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
                .then(function(data) {
                    $scope.postRequest(data);
                });
            $scope.postRequest = function(val) {
                this.items = val;
                this.title = val[0].title;
            };
        }],
        link: function ($scope, $el, $attr  ) {

            var template = '<div class=\"test\">{{this.title}}</div>' +
                '<div class=\"tes\" ng-repeat=\"item in this.items\">'+
                '<div class=\"test1\">{{item.title}}</div>'+
                '</div>';

            var e = $compile(template)($scope);
            $el.after(e);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: This post can tell you what that error means:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22123769/rangeerror-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-why.  You do not have to compile in this instance though.  An example of when you might compile is say you did a GET request which returned some template...then you would need to manually compile it.

Comment: so essentially I need to push the results on to an array. How do I manually compile to see the values?

Comment: you are mixing `$scope` and `controllerAs` in the same directive, and this will generally lead to cases of confusion.  In particular, the `this` object inside the `$scope.postRequest` function is not a reference to the controller.  Also, in your template, you should be using `ctrl` instead of `this`.

Comment: you actually don't need a `link` function at all in your directive; I'm going to refactor the directive for you in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a refactored version of your directive.  Because you are using `controllerAs`, the reference to `$scope` can be removed entirely.  Also, a variable `ctrl` is created as an alias to the controller, for consistent access to the controller from inside callback functions.  Finally, the `link` function is removed and the `template` has been adjusted to reference `ctrl` instead of `this`.

The error

> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

is a result of using `this` in the template, which is referring to the DOM rather than the controller, in conjunction with `$compile`, essentially compiling the DOM into itself.

```js
function mydirective(myservice, $compile) {

  return {
    restrict: 'ACE',
    scope: {
      url: '=',
      title: '=',
    },
    controllerAs: 'ctrl',
    bindToController: true,
    controller: function() {
      var ctrl = this; //alias reference for use inside controller callbacks
      myservice.init('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
        .then(function(data) {
          ctrl.postRequest(data);
        });
      ctrl.postRequest = function(val) {
        ctrl.items = val;
        ctrl.title = val[0].title;
      };
    },
    template: '<div class=\"test\">{{ctrl.title}}</div>' +
      '<div class=\"tes\" ng-repeat=\"item in ctrl.items\">' +
      '<div class=\"test1\">{{item.title}}</div>' +
      '</div>'
  };
}
```

Please note this code hasn't been tested.