# angular $http.put() works but $http({method: 'PUT'}) does not

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to consolidate all my services which make api calls to the Rails back end into one.  Here's what it looks like:

```
angular.module('feeSuitesApp')
  .factory('FeeSuitesSvc', [
    '$http',
    function ($http) {
      var TransformInstance, Result;

      TransformInstance = function(FeeObj, obj){
        return new FeeObj(obj);
      };

      Result = function(feeSuiteObj){
        var servicePlural = feeSuiteObj.service + 's';
        return $http({
          method: feeSuiteObj.method,
          url: feeSuiteObj.url,
          params: feeSuiteObj.params,
          transformResponse: function(data){
            var w = angular.fromJson(data);
            angular.forEach(w[servicePlural], function(obj, idx){
              w[servicePlural][idx] = TransformInstance(feeSuiteObj.feeObj, obj);
            });
            return w;
          }
        })
      }

      return {
        promise: Result,
      };
  }]);
```

POST and GET work fine, but PUT gives me a `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

FeeRule looks like this:

```
angular.module('feeSuitesApp')
  .factory('FeeRule', function(){
    //constructor
  var FeeRule = function(obj){
    this.id = obj.id || null;
    this.name = obj.name || '';
    this.fee_suite_id = obj.fee_suite_id || null;
    this.fee_parameter_id = obj.fee_parameter_id || null;
    this.multiplier = obj.multiplier || 1;
    this.addend = obj.addend || 0;
  };

  return FeeRule;
});
```

however, if I make the following call everything works perfectly:

```
var url = '/api/v3/fee_rules/' + feeRule.id;
$http.put(url, { fee_rule: feeRule});
```

but if I use my service like this I get the stack overflow error:

```
var feeSuiteObj = {
  url: '/api/v3/fee_rules/' + feeRule.id,
  service: 'fee_rule',
  method: 'PUT',
  params: {
    fee_rule: feeRule
  },
  feeObj: FeeRule
};

FeeSuitesSvc.promise(feeSuiteObj).then(function(success){
    $state.go('root');
  },function(error){
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: what is `service` and `feeobj` and where is `data`? Object doesn't match docs. `params != data`

Comment: as per your error (RangeError) I guess your problem is being raised from here:  "angular.forEach(w[servicePlural],". see more http://stackoverflow.com/a/22123896/335905

Comment: Just an fyi but you can consolidate using the $resource library. In my project at work we have api calls constructed like the following where we can call GET, POST, PUT.

   function deleteTnApi($resource) {
        return $resource('/:api/orderNumber/:someNumber/orderVersion/:version', null, {
            'update': {method: 'PUT'}
        });

Answer (score 0):

see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage, there is no *service* nor *feeObj* config properties, also *params* is used to append serialized data to *GET* requests (not *PUT*). So try this:

```
var feeSuiteObj = {
  url: '/api/v3/fee_rules/' + feeRule.id,
  method: 'PUT',
  data: {
    fee_rule: feeRule
  }
};
```

if you need to pass *service* or *feeObj*, you can do it within data object:

```
data: {
  fee_rule: feeRule,
  service: 'fee_rule',
  feeObj: FeeRule
}
```