# Angular 2 :Uncaught (in promise): RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-services, angular2-directives

I just begin working with angular 2. so I try to display categories from data base using web service.

this is my forum.service.ts file

```
   public getCategories(){
        return this.http.get('http://localhost/ForumLaraAngular/public/api/forum').map((res: Response) => res.json());

     }
```

forum.component.ts:

```
categories:any;

  constructor(private forumService:ForumService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.forumService.getCategories().subscribe((data)=>{this.categories=data;})

}
```

forum.component.html:

```
<categories>
<ul>
<li *ngFor="let categ of categories"> {{categ.titre}}</li>
</ul>

</categories>
```

Any help please,thanks in  advance

Comment: what are you trying to fetch? Could it be a very long (too long) array? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22123769/rangeerror-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-why

Comment: To support the comment above, try to return a small array from the service and test if it is it

Comment: I just begin with 4 elements

Comment: Remove `<categories> </categories>`. Why did you use it for?

Comment: it's the selector

Comment: @TheUnreal Finally it's working after removing <categories></categories> thanks a lot :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Write following lines of code out of  selector

```
<ul>
<li *ngFor="let categ of categories"> {{categ.titre}}</li>
</ul>
```