# Java recursion output different from expected

Tags: java

Just when I thought I was starting to understand recursion this one seems simple when n is 1  but when n is 2  In my head I  end up with [[*, [, [,*]

```
public void ps (int n){

  if (n==0) {
    System.out.print ("*");  
  }
  else {
    System.out.print ("[");
    ps (n-1);
    System.out.print (",");
    ps (n-1);
    System.out.print ("]");
  }
}
```

Comment: well what do you think it should do and what does it do? Start with that.

Comment: @Jason signature of your method should look like `public void ps(int number)` instead of `Public void ps (int n)`.

Comment: Sorry was typing on my phone that type o  was not in the program

Comment: For 1 it's  [*,*] 2 it's [[*,*], [*,*]]

Comment: Well that's not at all what I typed

Comment: Edit your question. Make it clear. Tell what you want to achieve, what you expect to happen, and what happens instead. Use the preview, and don't post your question until it's perfectly clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  ps(2):
     Current output ""
     n != 0 so else: print [ output = "[" 
     call ps(1)
     ps(1):
       Current output "["
       n != 0 so else: print [ output = "[[" 
       call ps(0)
       ps(0):
        Current output "[["
         n == 0: print "*" output = "[[*"
         return
     ps (1): after first call
       output = "[[*"
       print "," output = "[[*,"
       call ps(0):
       ps(0):
         current output "[[*,"
         n == 0: print "*" output = "[[*,*"
         return
    ps(1): after second call
       output = "[[*,*"
       print "]" output = "[[*,*]"
       return
  ps(2): after first call
    output = "[[*,*]"
    print , output = "[[*,*],"
    call ps(1)
             ps(1):
       Current output [[*,*],
       n != 0 so else: print [ output = "[[*,*],[" 
       call ps(0)
       ps(0):
        Current output "[[*,*],[" 
         n == 0: print "*" output = "[[*,*],[*"
         return
     ps (1): after first call
       output = "[[*,*],[*"
       print "," output = "[[*,*],[*,"
       call ps(0):
       ps(0):
         current output "[[*,*],[*,"
         n == 0: print "*" output = "[[*,*],[*,*"
         return
    ps(1): after second call
       output = "[[*,*],[*,*"
       print "]" output = "[[*,*],[*,*]"
       return
   ps(2): after second call
       output = "[[*,*],[*,*]"
       print "]" output = "[[*,*],[*,*]]"
       return
```

Final output: `"[[*,*],[*,*]]"`

Comment: Thank you for your help just what I needed

Answer (score 0):

Well, you probably heard the terms `stack frame` and `call stack` already. They are quite important to understand what happens in a recursion.

My tip is to draw the `stack frames` in a tree, according to their invocation.

In this case it would look like:

```
ps(2)
  |
  |--ps(1)
  |    |
  |    |--ps(0)
  |
  |--ps(1)
  |    |
  |    |--ps(0)
```

Now add to this the output from each invocation, and you should be fine.

- As mentioned, on future questions try to explain what you expect or what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Call stack yes  stack frame no better back up it sounds like

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057443/explain-the-concept-of-a-stack-frame-in-a-nutshell -- Basically, it is the information passed to an invocation of a funtion, the most interesting part are the parameters, but it also includes stuff like a return address (what code should be executed when done) and an address where to put the return value (if it is not void) and such. The last two are normally taken for granted, but usefull to look at when learning recursion.