# Javascript execution context order

Tags: javascript, executioncontext

First of all, I call func1 and so it gets on top of the global execution context. And then it calls func2. What I wanna know is, after calling func2, does func1 immediately return or get off the execution stack? Or is it like, first func2 gets on top of func1 execution context, it returns and then func1 returns and finally we're back to global execution context?

```js
    func1();


function func1 () {

 func2();
}


function func2 () {

 const x = 2;
}
```

Comment: It works like a stack, but there's something called [tail call optimization](http://2ality.com/2015/06/tail-call-optimization.html).

Comment: Related [Explain the concept of a stack frame in a nutshell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057443/explain-the-concept-of-a-stack-frame-in-a-nutshell)

Comment: Also be wary that once you [get async methods (and you will) your call stack gets a lot more complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @peterMader this is not recursion. I think its an optimization thing, and i dont think that its really benefitial to optimize this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function calls are implemented as a stack. When `func1` is called, it immediately calls `func2`. When `func2` returns, it returns to the scope of `func1` and continue from there. Browser optimizations might realize that there are no more instructions after `func2()` and skip the chain back up, but that's implementation-dependent.

Comment: So func2 execution context gets popped off and then func1 execution context gets popped off?

Comment: @MagneticKode In general, yes. Modern JS engines are heavily optimized however, so the interpreter might be smart enough to never even go back into `func1`.

Comment: Thank you. That clears my confusion. I know it doesn't really matter anyway because if func2 was under func1, func2 would still have access to func1 variables because of scope chain even if func1 was no longer on the execution stack. I just like to be crystal clear when it comes to theory.

Comment: @MagneticKode *func2 would still have access to func1 variables* - This is not true. The scope of `func1` cannot be accessed by `func2`.

Comment: In this case, yes. I mean if func2 was inside func1.

Comment: @MagneticKode If `func2` is defined in `func1` then yes, `func2` would be able to access variables in the scope of`func1`.

Comment: Ya that's what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `func1` might immediately return after having called `func2()` since there is no further code to run, but in general that is not the case. Consider

```
function func1() {
    const message = "example";
    func2();
    console.log(message);
}
```

then the log would still run in the execution of `func1` after having popped the execution context of `func2()` (when returning from there).

Execution contexts are managed in a stack - the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) - and will get pushed and popped only one at a time. When popping a stack frame, it resumes execution where it left off when the stack frame was pushed.