# Accessing pushed args after calling a routine

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, x86-16, calling-convention

I am learning x86 assembly using FreeDOS and nasm. I have this little test program that all it does is print A to the screen and exits.

It works fine if I don't use the Write routine.

But what seems to be happening is when I push A on to the stack then call Write it places the next IP on to the stack and when I pop off A in the routine I get the IP not the value I pushed.

I am sure it is something simple but I don't see the issue.

```
segment data                    ; start of data segment

segment code                    ; start of code segment
..start:

label1:
top:
        push 'A'
        call Write
        mov ah, 4ch
        mov al, 0
        int 21h

Write:
        pop dx
        mov ah, 02h
        int 21h
        ret
end:
        mov ah, 4ch             ;exit
        mov al, 0               ;exit code 0
        int 21h                 ;call intr

segment stack class=stack       ; start of stack segment
        resb 512
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how it is *supposed* to work. Calling into a function pushes the return address on the stack. So, when your function is entered, the top of the stack will be return address and not what you previously pushed.

In 32-bit code you could now just use the stack pointer directly to access the previously pushed value (something like `[esp+4]` or `[esp+2]` in 16-bit mode), but this is not possible with pure 16-bit assembly with only 16-bit addressing modes and their limited choice of registers (not including `[sp]`).

The normal way is to set up `bp` as a [frame pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057443/explain-the-concept-of-a-stack-frame-in-a-nutshell) from which you have random access to your stack frame, including stack args or any local vars you reserve space for.

```
Write:
    push bp            ; Save previous value of bp so it won't get lost
    mov bp, sp         ; Set bp ("base pointer") to current stack pointer position

    mov dx, [bp+4]     ; Get argument from stack
    mov ah, 02h
    int 21h

    mov sp, bp         ; Restore stack pointer
    pop bp             ; Restore value of base pointer

    ret 2              ; Indicate how many bytes should be popped from stack after return
```

Instead of `pop dx`, we use `mov dx, [bp+4]` here. At this point, `[bp]` would be the previous `bp` value (since it was last pushed before `bp` was assigned to `sp`), `[bp+2]` would be the return address, and `[bp+4]` your first argument.

(Remember that the stack grows downwards, that's why you need `+4` and not `-4` here.)

Also, when you return, you have to be sure that the argument is removed from the stack.  You can either let the caller clean up or use `ret` with the number of bytes to remove as argument.  It's an extra `sp += n` *after* popping the return address.  In your case, `ret 2` would implement callee-pops for this function.

Comment: `[sp+2]` is not a valid addressing mode.  Remember that in 16 bit modes, the base register must always be one of `bx` and `bp` and the index register must always be one of `si` or `di`; either or both can be absent.  To fix this, either use a 32 bit addressing mode (might not be available on OPs system) or establish a proper stack frame.

Comment: Oh, right, it's ages since I last used 16 bits. Give me a sec.

Comment: I tweaked some wording, including in the last paragraph where you said "either" but forgot to mention the other option (caller-pops).  Also, 32-bit addressing modes *are* usable in 16-bit mode, on 386-compatible CPUs.  (Also requires that SP is zero-extended into ESP)

Comment: that was it, thanks. I guess I need to read up on 16-bit assembly.