# how to get the caller's filename, method name in python

Tags: python

for example, `a.boo` method calls `b.foo` method.  In `b.foo` method, how can I get a's file name (I don't want to pass `__file__` to `b.foo` method)...

Comment: thanks for your answer, and I found here is the best for me now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711184/how-to-use-inspect-to-get-the-callers-info-from-callee

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can use the `inspect` module to achieve this:

```
frame = inspect.stack()[1]
module = inspect.getmodule(frame[0])
filename = module.__file__
```

Comment: `inspect.getmodule()` may return `None` under some conditions, so a more bulletproof way is:  

```filename = frame[0].f_code.co_filename```

Comment: Why not just `filename = frame[1]` (or `frame.filename` in python 3.5+)?

Answer (score 41):

## Python 3.5+

### One-liner

To get the full filename (with path and file extension), use in the callee:

```
import inspect
filename = inspect.stack()[1].filename
```

### Full filename vs filename only

To retrieve the caller's filename use [inspect.stack()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.stack). Additionally, the following code also trims the path at the beginning and the file extension at the end of the full filename:

```
# Callee.py
import inspect
import os.path

def get_caller_info():
  # first get the full filename (including path and file extension)
  caller_frame = inspect.stack()[1]
  caller_filename_full = caller_frame.filename

  # now get rid of the directory (via basename)
  # then split filename and extension (via splitext)
  caller_filename_only = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(caller_filename_full))[0]

  # return both filename versions as tuple
  return caller_filename_full, caller_filename_only
```

It can then be used like so:

```
# Caller.py
import callee

filename_full, filename_only = callee.get_caller_info()
print(f"> Filename full: {filename_full}")
print(f"> Filename only: {filename_only}")

# Output
# > Filename full: /workspaces/python/caller_filename/caller.py
# > Filename only: caller
```

#### Official docs

- [os.path.basename()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename): to remove the path from the filename (still includes the extension)
- [os.path.splitext()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext): to split the the filename and the file extension

Answer (score 19):

Inspired by ThiefMaster's answer but works also if `inspect.getmodule()` returns `None`:

```
frame = inspect.stack()[1]
filename = frame[0].f_code.co_filename
```

Answer (score 8):

This can be done with the [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) module, specifically [`inspect.stack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.stack):

```
import inspect
import os.path

def get_caller_filepath():
    # get the caller's stack frame and extract its file path
    frame_info = inspect.stack()[1]
    filepath = frame_info[1]  # in python 3.5+, you can use frame_info.filename
    del frame_info  # drop the reference to the stack frame to avoid reference cycles

    # make the path absolute (optional)
    filepath = os.path.abspath(filepath)
    return filepath
```

Demonstration:

```
import b

print(b.get_caller_filepath())
# output: D:\Users\Aran-Fey\a.py
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use the `traceback` module:

```
import traceback
```

and you can print the back trace like this:

```
print traceback.format_stack()
```

I haven't used this in years, but this should be enough to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Reading all these solutions, it seems like this works as well?

```
import inspect
print inspect.stack()[1][1]
```

The second item in the frame already is the file name of the caller, or is this not robust?

Comment: Sure it is robust, it is just not very readable. Therefore, `inspect.stack()[1].filename` is the preferred syntax which is supported as of Python 3.5.

Answer (score 1):

Had problems with solutions above (returned '<string>' for some reason). This is mine:

```
traceback.format_stack()[0].split('"')[1]
```