# Get caller function's absolute path to its file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, path

If there is method `t1` in file `a.py` and there is a file `b.py`, which calls method `t1` from `a.py` file. How do I get full/absolute path to `b.py` file inside `t1` method?

With inspect module (just like here: [how to get the caller's filename, method name in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13699283/how-to-get-the-callers-filename-method-name-in-python)), I can get relative path to file, but it seems it does not contain absolute path (or there is some other attribute object, to access to get it?).

As an example:

**a.py:**

```
def t1():
    print('callers absolute path')
```

**b.py:**

```
from a import t1
t1()  # should print absolute path for `b.py`
```

Comment: Shouldn't `t1()` return th absolute path for `a.py`?

Comment: So you're asking how to turn a relative path into an absolute path...?

Comment: @DirtyBit no. To get `a.py` path, you simply use `__file__` or `sys.path[0]`. But I need caller's path, not the called method's path.

Comment: @Aran-Fey If it does not return absolute path, then yes. I wonder if using combining with `os.path.realpath` would return correct absolute path all the time? Cause `realpath` function combines current working directory with relative path.

Comment: `__file__` is always a valid path, i.e. yes, it's relative to the current working directory. (Unless you've changed the CWD in your code, but then it's your own fault...)

Answer (score 5):

```
import os
import inspect


def get_cfp(real: bool = False) -> str:
    """Return caller's current file path.

    Args:
        real: if True, returns full path, otherwise relative path
            (default: {False})
    """
    frame = inspect.stack()[1]
    p = frame[0].f_code.co_filename
    if real:
        return os.path.realpath(p)
    return p
```

Running from another module:

```
from module import my_module
p1 = my_module.get_cfp()
p2 = my_module.get_cfp(real=True)
print(p1)
print(p2)
```

**Prints:**

```
test_path/my_module_2.py
/home/user/python-programs/test_path/my_module_2.py
```

Comment: `frame = inspect.stack()[1]` `p = frame[0].f_code.co_filename` - very useful lines. After some edits I included this in my local proprietary package in order to save some files in the same folder where calling script is (instead of changing relative path using `os` all the time or passing whole path string). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using `sys._getframe()`:

**a1.py**:

```
import sys
def t1():
    print(sys._getframe().f_code)
```

**a2.py**:

```
from a1 import t1
t1()  # should print absolute path for `b.py`
```

**Hence**:

```
py -m a2.py
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
<code object t1 at 0x0000029BF394AB70, file "C:\Users\dirtybit\PycharmProjects\a1.py", line 2>
```

**EDIT**:

Using `inspect`:

**a1.py**:

```
import inspect
def t1():
    print("Caller: {}".format(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))
```

**a2.py**:

```
from a1 import t1
t1()  # should print absolute path for `b.py`
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Caller: C:\Users\dirtybit\PycharmProjects\a1.py
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it with the `os` module in python.

```
>>> import a
>>> os.path.abspath(a.__file__)
```

Comment: This will give you path for current file, not for callers file.

Answer (score 0):

Using the os module you can do the following:

**a.py**

```
import os

def t1(__file__):
    print(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

**b.py**

```
from a import t1
t1(__file__)  # shoult print absolute path for `b.py`
```

With this, you could call `t1(__file__` and get the absolute path for any file.

Comment: I know, but thats not what I need. I need to get that path inside `a.py`. It should be the job for `a.py` to provide that, not for `b.py`.

Comment: print(os.path.abspath("b.py"))

Comment: Well, you still need to provide callers filename, so no good:)

Answer (score 0):

The trick consists in recovering both the current working directory **and** the relative path w.r.t that directory to the caller file (here `b.py`). The join does the rest.

**a.py:**

```
    import os
    import sys
    def t1():
        namespace = sys._getframe(1).f_globals
        cwd = os.getcwd()
        rel_path = namespace['__file__']
        abs_path= os.path.join(cwd,rel_path)
        print('callers absolute path!',abs_path)
```

**b.py:**

```
    from a import t1
    t1()  # prints absolute path for `b.py`
```

The trick does not work for jupyter notebooks unfortunately..