# Get directory of project from where python plugin was invoked

Tags: python, plugins, hook

I have implemented a plugin to be used by other Python projects. I want this plugin to be able to obtain the root directory of the project which called it. How would this be possible?

Comment: Use `__file__` attribute along with `os.path.abspath` to get the desired path. @D. Basil

Comment: @Vishnudev
Would it be this - ```root = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))```

Comment: Just `os.path.dirname(__file__)` should work.

Comment: This wouldn't give me the root directory of where the plugin is, correct? I need the root of the project from where the plugin was called.

Comment: What do you mean by root? How can you distinguish a root?

Comment: The plugin would be defined in a separate project, which my current working project imports. I need the plugin to access the root of the project which is calling it, not the root of the project where the plugin is defined.

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55469447/get-caller-functions-absolute-path-to-its-file