# How to get the calling class name inside a function

Tags: python

I have 2 classes with a method called `pick_up_phone`.

```
class Work(object):

   def pick_up_phone(self):
       make_call()

class Home(object):

    def pick_up_phone(self):
       make_call()
```

The function `make_call` is not part of the class. How can I print the name of class that instigated the function within the function itself without passing anything to that function?

For example something like...

```
def make_call()
  print(????__.class__.__name__)???? <--- prints Home or Work class
```

Comment: Odd requirements. Why wouldn't you either make it part of the super class, or pass in the instance as a parameter?

Comment: It is odd, but the example explains the situation I have where I don't control the calling class only the function. I need to determine which class called my function. I know how to achieve this using ``self.__class__.__name__`` however, with a function this wouldn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use inspect to get the caller's info from callee in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711184/how-to-use-inspect-to-get-the-callers-info-from-callee-in-python)

Comment: You can [access the stack frame using `inspect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#the-interpreter-stack)

Comment: @PeterWood I looked at that answer, but I don't understand how it relates very well. Maybe I just don't understand the answer given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [inspect](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html) module:

```
from inspect import getouterframes, currentframe


def make_call():
    print getouterframes(currentframe())[-1][-2][0]


class Work(object):
    def pick_up_phone(self):
        make_call()


class Home(object):
    def pick_up_phone(self):
        make_call()


Home().pick_up_phone()
Work().pick_up_phone()
```

Output:

```
Home().pick_up_phone()

Work().pick_up_phone()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get call stack from traceback module (see examples here [Print current call stack from a method in Python code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156023/print-current-call-stack-from-a-method-in-python-code)), but as Daniel said it is very bad approach in most cases.