# Is there a reliable way to get the path of the caller module from a Python function that is executed within a Sphinx conf.py?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I'm running some custom Python code in Sphinx and **need to get the path to the caller module**.  (Essentially this is the caller's `__file__` object; I need to interpret a filename relative to this location.)

I can get the filename from `inspect.stack()` as per [How to use inspect to get the caller's info from callee in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711184), but apparently I need to interpret this filename in the context of the Python startup directory. (Sometimes `inspect.stack()[k][1]` is an absolute path but sometimes it is a relative path like `conf.py`; the [`inspect.stack()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#the-interpreter-stack) function doesn't seem to document this but [unutbu claims in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3711243/44330) that it is relative to the Python startup directory. )

Sphinx does some unintentionally evil things like this comment:

```
# This file is execfile()d with the current directory set to its
# containing dir.
```

so `os.path.abspath(filename)` doesn't work, and

```
# If extensions (or modules to document with autodoc) are in another directory,
# add these directories to sys.path here. If the directory is relative to the
# documentation root, use os.path.abspath to make it absolute, like shown here.
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('extensions'))
```

so `sys.path[0]` is corrupted by the time my code gets to it.

How do I find the startup directory in Python, if `sys.path` has been modified?

Or is there another way to get the path to the caller module?

---

If I run [Jean-François Fabre's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39299596/44330)

```
for file,line,w1,w2 in traceback.extract_stack():
    sys.stdout.write('  File "{}", line {}, in {}\n'.format(file,line,w1))
```

I get this:

```
File "c:\app\python\anaconda\1.6.0\Scripts\sphinx-build-script.py", line 5, in <module>
File "c:\app\python\anaconda\1.6.0\lib\site-packages\Sphinx-1.4.1-py2.7.egg\sphinx\__init__.py", line 51, in main
File "c:\app\python\anaconda\1.6.0\lib\site-packages\Sphinx-1.4.1-py2.7.egg\sphinx\__init__.py", line 92, in build_main
File "c:\app\python\anaconda\1.6.0\lib\site-packages\Sphinx-1.4.1-py2.7.egg\sphinx\cmdline.py", line 243, in main
File "c:\app\python\anaconda\1.6.0\lib\site-packages\Sphinx-1.4.1-py2.7.egg\sphinx\application.py", line 155, in __init__
File "conf.py", line 512, in setup
[more lines elided, the conf.py is the one that matters]
```

so the problem is that I need to find the path to `conf.py` but the current directory has been changed by Sphinx so I can't just do `os.path.abspath(caller_filename)`

Comment: `os.getcwd()` is the directory where python is running `__file__` will tell you the path and filename of any .py file ...

Comment: other than that i dont know what you mean by "startup directory"

Comment: "but I need to interpret this filename in the context of some directory." what do you mean?

Comment: I can't use `__file__`, I need to find the *caller's* `__file__`

Comment: @JoranBeasley I know both of those facts already and neither helps me.

Comment: What's the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I would rather avoid playing the XY-problem game if that's what you're thinking of @jonrsharpe. I need to get the path to the caller's module.

Comment: @JasonS does `sys.argv[0]` work in this case which wil be the path to the *actual* script?

Comment: thanks NinjaPuppy -- nope, that doesn't work for me in this case either since it returns the Sphinx build script c:\app\python\anaconda\1.6.0\Scripts\sphinx-build-script.py which calls execfile() to run my conf.py

Comment: If Sphinx execfile()s a script `with the current directory set to its containing dir` then a "relative path" within that process should be _relative to that_? So if **Python** just says `conf.py` in that Traceback, then it seems that must be relative to the "containing dir". (Seems logical, not tested)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bah, I'm just going to get around the issue by allowing callers to pass in their `__file__` value  :-(

my function:

```
def do_something(app, filename, relroot=None):
   if relroot is None:
      relroot = '.'
   else:
      relroot = os.path.dirname(relroot)
   path = os.path.join(relroot, filename)
   ...
```

in conf.py:

```
def setup(app):
   mymodule.do_something(app, 'path/to/file', relroot=__file__)
```

Comment: I just love stone-throwers who downvote a valid answer.

Answer (score 4):

you can get what you want using the `traceback` module. I've written this sample code in PyScripter:

```
import traceback,sys

def demo():
   for file,line,w1,w2 in traceback.extract_stack():
       sys.stdout.write('  File "{}", line {}, in {}\n'.format(file,line,w1))

def foo():
    demo()

foo()
```

which gives on my Windows PC running PyScripter:

```
  File "C:\Users\dartypc\AppData\Roaming\PyScripter\remserver.py", line 63, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\dartypc\AppData\Roaming\PyScripter\remserver.py", line 60, in main
  File "C:\Program Files\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\utils\server.py", line 227, in start
  File "C:\Program Files\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\utils\server.py", line 139, in accept
  File "C:\Users\dartypc\AppData\Roaming\PyScripter\remserver.py", line 14, in _accept_method
  File "C:\Program Files\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\utils\server.py", line 191, in _serve_client
  File "C:\Program Files\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\protocol.py", line 391, in serve_all
  File "C:\Program Files\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\protocol.py", line 382, in serve
  File "C:\Program Files\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\protocol.py", line 350, in _dispatch
  File "C:\Program Files\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\protocol.py", line 298, in _dispatch_request
  File "C:\Program Files\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\protocol.py", line 528, in _handle_call
  File "<string>", line 420, in run_nodebug
  File "C:\DATA\jff\data\python\stackoverflow\simple_traceback.py", line 10, in <module>
  File "C:\DATA\jff\data\python\stackoverflow\simple_traceback.py", line 8, in foo
  File "C:\DATA\jff\data\python\stackoverflow\simple_traceback.py", line 4, in demo
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work; I still get stuck with a relative file (I'll comment in my answer)

Comment: damn: tough luck! Would trying to interpret `PYTHONPATH` environment variable a possibility? At least it is not butchered like `sys.path`.

Comment: no, I think the problem is that Sphinx runs `execfile()` and this messes up introspection.

Comment: oh, that's why they removed it in python 3 then :) do you know where this call to `execfile` is done? wouldn't it be possible to patch the file so it avoids the use of `execfile`?