# Python variable scope across modules

Tags: python, variables, scope

*The title might be misleading or inaccurate, so please correct me if I'm wrong.*

I have a package structured like this:

```
common
    __init__.py
foo.py
```

And here are the codes:

`common/__init__.py`

```
name = 'name_common'

def print_current_file_name():
    print('current file name: ' +  __file__)

def print_name():
    print('name is: ' + eval('name'))
```

`foo.py`

```
from common import print_current_file_name, print_name

name = 'name_foo'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print_current_file_name()
    print_name()
```

If I do this:

```
>>> python foo.py
```

I'll get this:

```
current file name: /tmp/common/__init__.py
name is: name_common
```

But I expect the results to be:

```
current file name: /tmp/common/foo.py
name is: name_foo
```

What did I miss? How can I make this right?
I don't even know which keywords should I google...

*The use of `eval` is weird, but these codes are just for demonstration purpose only.*

Answer (score 0):

That's not at all how variables work in Python, or in any language I'm aware of.

The global scope of a function is always where it is defined, not where it is executed. There is no way for `print_name` to access the value of `name` in foo.py.

Rather, you should pass it in as a parameter. Or, depending on what you actually want to do, you might want to create a class that defines the value of `name` at class level.

Comment: I agree, but I'm just wondering if there's any way to achieve this (without using `class`)

Comment: @amigcamel You are describing a dynamically scoped language (prominent examples are Scheme and shell); Python is statically scoped.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is possible.

I Found a similar question:
[How to use inspect to get the caller's info from callee in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3711184)

And I think this is what the built-in library `inspect` comes for.

`common/__init__.py`

```
from os.path import abspath
import inspect


name = 'name_common'

def print_current_file_name():

    print('current file name: ' + abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe().f_back)))
    # or
    print('current file name: ' + abspath(inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_globals['__file__']))

def print_name():
    print('name is: ' + inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_globals['name'])
```

Finally,

```
$ python foo.py
current file name: /tmp/common/foo.py
name is: name_foo
```