# Update function name in logging

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-logging

I am currently using the following code to log messages based on their *log_level* in customized fashion.
What i am struggling is how to update or change the function name in the common `LOG_MSG` function.

Currently it logs all messages with function name as `LOG_MSG`, I want to replace it with the actual function names `FunctionNum1` or `FunctionNum2`.

```
import logging
import inspect

INFO = "INFO"
DEBUG = "DEBUG"
WARN = "WARNING"
ERROR = "ERROR"

def LOG_MSG(level, msg_str, msg_val,tee_output):

    if msg_val == None:
        msg_val = ""

    if(level == INFO):
        logging.info ( msg_str + msg_val )
    elif(level == DEBUG):
        logging.debug ( msg_str + msg_val )
    elif(level == WARN):
        logging.warn ( msg_str + msg_val )
    elif(level == ERROR):
        logging.error ( msg_str + msg_val )

    if(tee_output):
        print ( msg_str + msg_val )

date_strftime_format = "%d-%b-%y %H:%M:%S"
message_format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(module)s - %(funcName)s: %(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(filename = 'log_messages.log', format = message_format, datefmt = date_strftime_format,level=logging.DEBUG)

def FunctionNum1():
    this_function_name = inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_name
    print this_function_name

    LOG_MSG(INFO,"This is an Info Msg=","Any Value",1)
    LOG_MSG(WARN,"This is a Warning Msg",None,0)
    LOG_MSG(INFO,"This is an Info Msg",None,1)

def FunctionNum2():
    this_function_name = inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_name
    print this_function_name
    somevalue = "someValue"
    LOG_MSG(DEBUG,"This is a Debug Msg = ",somevalue,1)
    LOG_MSG(INFO,"This is an Info Msg=","12",1)
    LOG_MSG(ERROR,"This is a Error Msg",None,1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    FunctionNum1()
    FunctionNum2()
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
20-Apr-21 15:55:58 INFO log_utility - LOG_MSG: This is an Info Msg=Any Value
20-Apr-21 15:55:58 WARNING log_utility - LOG_MSG: This is a Warning Msg
20-Apr-21 15:55:58 INFO log_utility - LOG_MSG: This is an Info Msg
20-Apr-21 15:55:58 DEBUG log_utility - LOG_MSG: This is a Debug Msg= someValue
20-Apr-21 15:55:58 INFO log_utility - LOG_MSG: This is an Info Msg=12
20-Apr-21 15:55:58 ERROR log_utility - LOG_MSG: This is a Error Msg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so by changing your logger's information (after importing the logging module) :

```py
logger = logging.getLogger() # load logging manager
oldMakeRecord = logger.makeRecord

def customMakeRecord(*args, **kwargs):
    # get usual record information
    rv = oldMakeRecord(*args, **kwargs)

    # change function name with what you want
    rv.funcName = "abc"

    return rv

# replace original manager with new one
logger.makeRecord = customMakeRecord
```

Which outputs (in *log_messages.log*):

```
20-Apr-21 14:08:39 INFO main - abc: This is an Info Msg=Any Value
20-Apr-21 14:08:39 WARNING main - abc: This is a Warning Msg
20-Apr-21 14:08:39 INFO main - abc: This is an Info Msg
20-Apr-21 14:08:39 DEBUG main - abc: This is a Debug Msg = someValue
20-Apr-21 14:08:39 INFO main - abc: This is an Info Msg=12
20-Apr-21 14:08:39 ERROR main - abc: This is a Error Msg
```

With a bit of tweaking here and there, I'm pretty confident you'll be able to find the function name automatically ([How to use inspect to get the caller's info from callee in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711184/how-to-use-inspect-to-get-the-callers-info-from-callee-in-python) might be a good source of information).

There might be a better way to do this though, I don't use the logging & inspect modules that much.

**EDIT : More complete solution**

We can create a function that will update the logger with the given function name ; and use it every time we try to log something. When we do so, we can use the `inspect` module to find the correct function name to give as a parameter.

```py
def update_logger(function_name: str):
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    oldMakeRecord = logger.makeRecord

    def customMakeRecord(*args, **kwargs):
        rv = oldMakeRecord(*args, **kwargs)
        rv.funcName = function_name
        return rv

    logger.makeRecord = customMakeRecord

def LOG_MSG(level, msg_str, msg_val,tee_output):
    # find function name with inspect module
    caller_function_name = inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_code.co_name
    update_logger(function_name=caller_function_name)

    # the rest is the normal behavior of the log_msg function
    if msg_val == None:
        msg_val = ""

    if(level == INFO):
        logging.info ( msg_str + msg_val )
    elif(level == DEBUG):
        logging.debug ( msg_str + msg_val )
    elif(level == WARN):
        logging.warn ( msg_str + msg_val )
    elif(level == ERROR):
        logging.error ( msg_str + msg_val )

    if(tee_output):
        print ( msg_str + msg_val )
```

The *log_messages.log* file now contains :

```
22-Apr-21 13:41:58 INFO logging_format - FunctionNum1: This is an Info Msg=Any Value
22-Apr-21 13:41:58 WARNING logging_format - FunctionNum1: This is a Warning Msg
22-Apr-21 13:41:58 INFO logging_format - FunctionNum1: This is an Info Msg
22-Apr-21 13:41:58 DEBUG logging_format - FunctionNum2: This is a Debug Msg = someValue
22-Apr-21 13:41:58 INFO logging_format - FunctionNum2: This is an Info Msg=12
22-Apr-21 13:41:58 ERROR logging_format - FunctionNum2: This is a Error Msg
```

Comment: this is hardcoding function name, but i want "abc" to be any function that calls `LOG_MSG`

Comment: Yes, you are right ; I just wrote about the crux of the matter. A more complete solution would replace the logger before calling `LOG_MSG` and each time it is done, the function name would be guessed with the `inspect` module. I will try yo update my solution when I have the time.

Comment: I made an edit to the solution above. It should now work as intended.

Comment: Thanks that worked, What do you think is the proper approach for this kind of requirement

Comment: I honestly don't know. In terms of code, there might be a better solution, maybe more elegant or efficient ; in terms of elegance, maybe we can avoid modifying the `LOG_MSG` function by using a decorator instead ; and in terms of efficiency, one would need to test how much time is taken by adding these lines of code and see if it is a prohibitive addition. But other than that, I think you would have a valid approach as long as it works and doesn't make your code hard to read, you can always improve on it later (however, don't quote me on this !).