# Calling a function that lives in `a.py`, that gets the filename of `b.py`

Tags: python

I have two files `a.py` and `b.py`.

`a.py` is where my functions live, and `b.py` is where my function calls live.

From `b.py`, I need to call a function that lives in `a.py`, that gets the filename of `b.py`.

`a.py`

```py
import os

# functions
def foo():
    filename = os.path.basename(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    """ and then some other stuff """
```

`b.py`

```py
from a import *

# function calls
foo()
```

But obviously `__file__` in `a.py` is:

```
a.py
```

---

Is there a way to make this work without doing this:

`a.py`

```py
import os

# functions
def foo():
    """ some other stuff """
```

`b.py`

```py
from a import *

filename = os.path.basename(os.path.realpath(__file__))

# function calls
foo()
```

Which is completely possible, just much less elegant.

Comment: I think you should pass the filename to the `foo` function in `a.py`.

Comment: Yes that makes sense, although for my purpose that requires an equivalent extra step to the extra step that I'm already using.  `b.py` will always be a new file.  edit - is there a reason this question got downvoted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need the filename you can just `import sys` and use `sys.argv[0]`. If you want to use the filename and do some other things you can pass `sys.argv[0]` into foo.

If you really want to have all the functionality live in `a.py` you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711184/how-to-use-inspect-to-get-the-callers-info-from-callee-in-python).

Comment: @mathbike: If what you want is in the link I posted you can prob go ahead and mark as duplicate :)