# How can a child module get its parent module in python?

Tags: python, import, module, python-importlib

My module what know who call its function, like

a.py

```
importlib.import_module("b")
b.b()
```

b.py

```
def b():
    importlib.import_module("c")
    print(parent_module)
    c.c()
```

c.py

```
import c

def c():
    print(parent_module)
```

I want `b()` print module a, and `c()` print b

I tried this func

```
def get_parent_name():
    print('get parent module')
    print(os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(getframeinfo(stack()[-1][0]).filename))[0])
```

but it can only get the toppest module, like

`b()` print `a` and `c()` print `a`

Comment: This qustion might solve my problem
[how-to-use-inspect-to-get-the-callers-info-from-callee-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711184/how-to-use-inspect-to-get-the-callers-info-from-callee-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

It's another answer [Get __name__ of calling function's module in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095543/get-name-of-calling-functions-module-in-python),
I dont recommand to use `inspect.stack[2]` because when i use it to get the caller's module name that i can get "inspect" only, so it wrong.
I recommand to use [image]
this method.You can get the caller module by this func

```
def caller_module():
    frame = inspect.currentframe()
    frame = frame.f_back.f_back
    return inspect.getmodule(frame)
```